# how can i use curl to check 350 pages on a website?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to pick-out some numbers on this Scene website: http://www.ds-scene.net/?s=releases&p=1

I want to put a number in and get the corresponding name. I have it working with the following code:

```
<?php
    function curlOpen($url){
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Firefox/3.0.5');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        $page = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $page;
        //\
    }

    $pageNum = $_GET['pageNum'];

    if(empty($pageNum)) { 
    $dsScene = curlOpen("http://www.ds-scene.net/?s=releases");
    } else {
    $dsScene = curlOpen("http://www.ds-scene.net/?s=releases&p=$pageNum");
    }
    $pattern = '#title="(.*?)"><b>(.*?)</b></a><br /><span class=\'smallTxt\'>#';
    preg_match_all($pattern,$dsScene,$match);


    $pattern = '#<td class="romlistpad"><div align="center" class="romlistTxt"><b>([0-9]{4})</b>#';
    preg_match_all($pattern,$dsScene,$match_number);

    if(in_array('5915', $match_number[1])) {
    $key = array_search('5915', $match_number[1]);
    echo "$key Found It on page: $pageNum - Corresponding name is ".$match[2][$key];
    } else {
        $pageNum++;
        header('Location: auto-add.php?pageNum='.$pageNum.'');
    }

    ?>
```

However as there are over 350 pages on that website, If i enter a number which is on page 50+ the browser just ends saying Redirect loop.

Is there a better / faster way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure whether the redirect loop takes into account query string parameters, try setting up your .htaccess to detect a URI string for the page number, then extracting that from the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  this will stop the redirect loop error as it will consider it a different page.

Answer (score 0):

Using URI to determine the page request, set in your .htaccess `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ auto-add.php?/$1 [L]` then use something like:

```
$uri = explode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$pagenum = end($uri);

..

$pageNum++;
header('Location: /'.$pageNum);
```

this ofcourse means you have to allow your webserver to use the .htaccess